# UIView Subclass, touch event

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a subclass of `UIView`. I need to display a new UI-View whenever I detect a touch event.

I know that I have to override the following method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

My problem is that I don't know how to display a full screen view.

I have tried the following:

```
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIView *mysubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame : screenSize];
[self.window addSubview:mysubview];
```

But I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it.

Can anyone give me advice?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I use `mySubView.frame = self.view.frame`;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the view to the window, why not just add it as a subview of the view intercepting touches?

```
UIView *mySubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
[self addSubview:mySubview];
```

After clarification it would appear that the custom view is a kind of button, and you want the new view to be a fullscreen view somewhere else in the hierarchy. This is really a job for a `UIViewController` that knows where to put the new view. You could use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the custom view instead of implementing your own touch handling code, with a `UIViewController` with a full screen view as the target. In the gesture recognizer action method you can then create your new view and add it as a subview of the `UIViewController`s hierarchy.

Comment: because the view which is listening to the touch event, is not a full screen view, it only has 100px in height and is located on the bottom of the screen